# Suspended tty output when trying to run background process

Tags: emacs, background, tty, oh-my-zsh

This problem was first noticed after installing ohmyzsh, although the problem persisted after uninstalling so I'm not totally sure what would have caused it.  It seems that I am unable to run processes in the background, as I get a "Suspended (tty output)" when I attempt to do so.  This is more an annoyance than a real problem, but it prevents me from running emacs in the background so I can continue using the same terminal for other tasks.  I've done quite a bit of searching on the internet for a solution and haven't been able to find anything that works.  I'm not looking for any kind of work around.  I'm interested in what caused this problem in the first place, and how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't mean you're trying to run a terminal-bound emacs in the background, do you?  If you run it in the foreground do you get a separate GUI frame?

Comment: No, if I run in the foreground the emacs GUI opens within the same terminal

Comment: In that case you are not using the GUI version at all.  An interactive application which runs in the terminal cannot be opened "in the background" because user interaction via that same terminal is needed by the application; so what you are seeing is expected.  Normally I would suspect you had installed a terminal-only Emacs package (it can be compiled without GUI support), but you seem to suggest that it was working recently.  In any case, if you figure out why Emacs is using the terminal instead of the GUI, you will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't use zsh or ohmyzsh, but the way I understand it is even if you uninstall, the configuration will still be there, because it modifies your `~/.zshrc`.  But again I'm not sure.  

You can suspend a terminal Emacs from within Emacs with `M-x suspend-frame`, which is bound to `C-z` by default, and is roughly equivalent to `C-z bg` in the shell.